# How to reset paging in a dataformwebpart?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-form-web-part, paging

In SPD 2010 I created a datasource which produces XML, based on the requests you send to it. The datasource works correctly, because when I put it on a page, it shows me the results I expect. Because the datasource can return a large number of results, I turned on paging in the dataformwebpart I use to present my datasource. This also, works as expected.

Troubles started when I made it possible to dynamically update the request to the datasource through a webpart connection from a SimpleHtml webpart.

The use case that goes wrong, is as follows:
- User opens page and sees a list of items (returned by the datasource).
- User goes to page 2 and decides that this is not what he wants to see.
- User therefore enters a search term and presses 'Search'.
- On the background: when user presses 'Search' the new search term is send through a webpart connection to the datasource, which dynamically reloads the data (without completely reloading the page), so user sees new results.
- However, user was on page 2 when he initiated the search and he still is on page 2 of the search results after the datasource got updated on the page.

The problem: how do I reset the paging in a dataformwebpart when the user enters a new search term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably work it so that you force a page refresh with the search term as a query string parameter that the data view web part can pick up and filter by.

Comment: That indeed is the best option, I think. Reworking my code took only thirty minutes and then it worked as expected. Thanks!